# Feedforward backPropagation networks to approximate linear functions using c#

Tags: c#, function, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm studying the **feedforward backPropagation networks** and using the "**Accord.Neuro**" libraries in **c#** (I used the ResilientBackpropagationLearning class that manages the "momentum" itself).

At this time my problem is to understand how to approximate the functions, especially those that are linear combinations of the input variables (hence the simplest ones).
Learning is supervised and one example is this: 3 variables -> **y (x1, x2, x3) = 2 * x1 + x2 + 5 * x3**.

I started studying functions on a single variable, then with 2, then with 3 variables and I managed to get results that I find satisfactory.
I managed to dimension the net and get good results.

---Case 3 Inputs:

- 3 INPUT
- 1 Hidden layer where there are 15 knots
- 1 OUTPUT

Training set, randomly generated on the input variable ranges, of 100 examples.
Training of 1000 Epochs(but also less).
I can get a network error of less than 0.001 and an average percentage error on the validation set of 1-2%.

---Try it now with 4 inputs

- 4 INPUT
- 1 Hidden layer where there are 25 knots
- 1 OUTPUT

Training set, randomly generated on the input variable ranges, of 500 examples
Training of 5000 Epochs
I can get a network error of less than 2.5 and an average percentage error on the validation set of 25-30%.

I've tried with so many configurations getting poor results. Even by increasing the number of examples up to 5000, epochs up to 100,000 and hidden nodes up to 50 I get an average percentage error on the validation set that improves but only up to 20-25%.

Why did I get so poor?

This is the base code of my program:
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_Learning_ResilientBackpropagationLearning.htm

This is my simple program:

```
using Accord.Neuro;
using Accord.Neuro.Learning;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4_1
{
    class Program
    {
        struct struttura
        {
            public double INPUT1, INPUT2, INPUT3, INPUT4, OUTPUT1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool needToStop = false;
            Random rr = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            int NE = 40, epoche = 50000, p;
            double ERRORE = 0.00001d;

            struttura[] EE = new struttura[NE];
            double error = 1; 
            double[][] input = new double[NE][];
            double[][] output = new double[NE][];
            for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u] = new double[4];
            for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) output[u] = new double[1];


            for (p = 0; p < NE; p++)
            {
                EE[p].INPUT1 = rr.Next(1, 200);
                EE[p].INPUT2 = rr.Next(1, 100);
                EE[p].INPUT3 = rr.Next(1, 50);
                EE[p].INPUT4 = rr.Next(1, 150);

                EE[p].OUTPUT1 = 0.1d * EE[p].INPUT2 + (2.0d / 3) * EE[p].INPUT1 + (7.0d / 10) * EE[p].INPUT3 + (2.0d / 3) * EE[p].INPUT4;    //  278.3333333   
            }
            for (p = 0; p < NE; p++)
            {
                for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][0] = EE[u].INPUT1 / 200;
                for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][1] = EE[u].INPUT2 / 100;
                for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][2] = EE[u].INPUT3 / 50;
                for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][3] = EE[u].INPUT3 / 150;

                for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) output[u][0] = EE[u].OUTPUT1 / 278.3333333;
            }

            // create neural network
            ActivationNetwork network = new ActivationNetwork(new SigmoidFunction(), 4, 8, 1);

            // create teacher
            var teacher = new ResilientBackpropagationLearning(network);   

            int i = 0;
            // loop
            while (!needToStop)
            {
                i++;
                // run epoch of learning procedure
                error = teacher.RunEpoch(input, output);
                // check error value to see if we need to stop
                if ((error < ERRORE) | (i == epoche)) needToStop = true;
                Console.WriteLine(i + "  " + error);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Esempi per epoca: "+NE+"     epoca: " + i + "     error: " + error + "\n\n"); // bastano 408 epoche con NE = 40

            double[] test1 = new double[] { 30.0d / 200, 80.0d / 100, 23.0d / 50, 100.0d/150};
            double[] ris1 = network.Compute(test1);
            double[] ris1Atteso1 = new double[] { 110.7666667d };
            Console.WriteLine("a: " + (ris1[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso1[0]);

            double[] test2 = new double[] { 150.0d / 200, 40.0d / 100, 3.0d / 50, 40.0d/150};
            double[] ris2 = network.Compute(test2);
            double[] ris1Atteso2 = new double[] { 132.7666667d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris2[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso2[0]);

            double[] test3 = new double[] { 15.0d / 200, 30.0d / 100, 45.0d / 50, 146.0d/150};
            double[] ris3 = network.Compute(test3);
            double[] ris1Atteso3 = new double[] { 141,8333333d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris3[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso3[0]);

            double[] test4 = new double[] { 3.0d / 200, 60.0d / 100, 12.0d / 50, 70.0d/150};
            double[] ris4 = network.Compute(test4);
            double[] ris1Atteso4 = new double[] {63.0666667d};
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris4[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso4[0]);

            double[] test5 = new double[] { 50.0d / 200, 2.0d / 100, 44.0d / 50, 15.0d/150};
            double[] ris5 = network.Compute(test5);
            double[] ris1Atteso5 = new double[] { 74,333333d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris5[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso5[0]);

            double[] test6 = new double[] { 180.0d / 200, 95.0d / 100, 25.0d / 50, 70.0d/150 };
            double[] ris6 = network.Compute(test6);
            double[] ris1Atteso6 = new double[] { 193.6666667 };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris6[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso6[0]);

            double[] test7 = new double[] { 22.0d / 200, 12.0d / 100, 2.0d / 50, 10.0d/150 };
            double[] ris7 = network.Compute(test7);
            double[] ris1Atteso7 = new double[] { 23.9333333d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris7[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso7[0]);

            double[] test8 = new double[] { 35.0d / 200, 5.0d / 100, 40.0d / 50, 120.0d/150 };
            double[] ris8 = network.Compute(test8);
            double[] ris1Atteso8 = new double[] { 131.8333333d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris8[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso8[0]);

            double[] test9 = new double[] { 115.0d / 200, 70.0d / 100, 50.0d / 50, 88.0d/150};
            double[] ris9 = network.Compute(test9);
            double[] ris1Atteso9 = new double[] { 177.3333333d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris9[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso9[0]);

            double[] test10 = new double[] { 18.0d / 200, 88.0d / 100, 1.0d / 50, 72.0d/150 };
            double[] ris10 = network.Compute(test10);
            double[] ris1Atteso10 = new double[] { 69.5d };
            Console.WriteLine("\na: " + (ris10[0] * 278.3333333d).ToString("") + "   " + ris1Atteso10[0]);

            double sum = Math.Abs(ris1[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso1[0])+ Math.Abs(ris2[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso2[0]) + Math.Abs(ris3[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso3[0]) + Math.Abs(ris4[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso4[0]) + Math.Abs(ris5[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso5[0]) 
                + Math.Abs(ris6[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso6[0]) + Math.Abs(ris7[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso7[0]) + Math.Abs(ris8[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso8[0]) + Math.Abs(ris9[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso9[0]) + Math.Abs(ris10[0] * 278.3333333d - ris1Atteso10[0]);

            double erroreMedio = sum / 10;

            double sumMedie = Math.Abs((ris1[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso1[0]) / (ris1Atteso1[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris2[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso2[0]) / (ris1Atteso2[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris3[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso3[0]) / (ris1Atteso3[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris4[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso4[0]) / (ris1Atteso4[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris5[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso5[0]) / (ris1Atteso5[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris6[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso6[0]) / (ris1Atteso6[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris7[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso7[0]) / (ris1Atteso7[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris8[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso8[0]) / (ris1Atteso8[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris9[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso9[0]) / (ris1Atteso9[0]))
            + Math.Abs((ris10[0] * 278.3333d - ris1Atteso10[0]) / (ris1Atteso10[0]));

        Console.WriteLine("\nErrore medio su 10 : "+ erroreMedio);

        Console.WriteLine("\nErrore % medio : " + (sumMedie/10)*100);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }





}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although i'm unfamiliar with Accord.
You seam to hit a classical problem that can happen to wrong dimensioned networks.
The neural network gets (extreme) good on training sets but not on practical sets.

I think you should try it with less hidden neurons.
As your network learned to much the training set resulting in that it cannt handle different data. As it would be better to score 85%-train and 79%-validation. As compared to 99%-train and 65%-validation. Notice that those % numbers the total % of both network is the same (85+79)=(99+65), but the first network would be better in solving unknown thing; and thats the general goal.

The term for what you have now is called over fitting.
Most often caused by that the network starts to act more like memory, it memorizes treshold, while it should be more about decision making in the unknown validation sets. Well i hope this helps.

Also be aware that with less hidden neurons, its also possible to not achieve near 100% on train set, but eventually its not about solving that one, keep that in mind.

Also not sure what you try to solve with it, but make sure your data set has the right neural network, for simple testing fun try to Irish-flower data set. My networks can score 199.16% or so on that in combined (trained+validation). You might try to beat that and if so give me an update :)

Comment: I have tried, as you suggested, with less neurons and also with a different number of training set elements and epochs.
I can not find any improvements

Comment: Well i dont know how you made the training set and validation set. But i am curious have you tried swapping them. ea is you training set  representable for your validation set ?. Or is there a to huge difference between them ?. Perhaps combine both data sets, and use a random generator to randomly devide into train and validation set. If that doesnt help, make sure there isnt something wrong with your validation (ea dont compare test input against validation output).(should be validation input against validation output).

Comment: I did a stupid, stupid mistake

for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][3] = EE[u].INPUT3 / 150;

It had to be

for (int u = 0; u < NE; u++) input[u][3] = EE[u].INPUT4 / 150;

Comment: Glad you found it,